# AndroidManifest file missing

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, barcode-scanner

i follow some tutorials to use the barcode scanner plugin for phonegap. But when i create a new android project from an existing source to create the barcode library [(step 6 in this page)](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3) i got the error: "AndroidManifest.xml file missing!". But in the root of the folder the file is present!
What is wrong?

Tnx in advance!

Comment: yes... i downloaded the library from "github"

Comment: It's useful to try building from the command line. If you don't normally do that, do:  "android update project -p . ; ant debug".  That sometimes gives you information you can use to solve an Eclipse problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened for me too. Actually the problem is the code you have downloaded does not consists of AndroidManifest.xml file. You just create another project based on your requirements & copy all the files into created project. It will work..

Otherwise

If your are using phonegap plugin means follow this link [Barcode Scanner plugin for Phonegap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner). First README file in this & follow the steps. its very easy....

Comment: Yes, i followed it! But i've got the error just after the step 1!

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml file missing

Comment: That is plugin dude. Plugin code downloaded from net does not have Manifest file. Plugin means you need to attach this plugin code to your original app code. after adding you need to provide that particular plugin in Plugin.xml file which resides in your resource folder..

Comment: yes, i've integrated the plugin to my app! I understood (i hope so) the following steps in the tutorials and i've applied them! But the error comes when i try to create the library.

Comment: I did it: "Add the 'LibraryProject' into Eclipse. File -> New Android Project -> create project from existing source". The source is the folder "LibraryProject". When i click to finish, i display the project in Eclipse, and immediately i get the error "AndroidMAnifest file missing". The file is present in the folder. I can set the project as "is Library", but no changes.

Comment: <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientat/******/> . Did you added the following one in your project Manifest file. if wont means it gives the error as Manifest file missing. Once go through 2nd point. Once check this, if still error means inform me..

Comment: It's an ADT bug, I think.  I had the same problem with one of my own projects, where the AndroidManifest.xml was clearly present.  Try changing the project build target (move back one version, maybe), and then change it back.  In my case that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed Step 6 in the tutorial you mention, using a github download of phonegap/phonegap-plugins today. Following those steps exactly, I get a new Android Project, in place where the source was downloaded, with the default project name of CaptureActivity, and an AndroidManifest.xml.

I would guess you've not followed the instructions in the first two sentences exactly as written.

Comment: I put the library in the workspace of eclipse... that was wrong! Now i've moved it out and the tutorial runs! Thank you, special thanks to "code_finder"!